# Why does django-haystack run the object preparation multiple times?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm having this in my `SearchIndex`:

```py
class UserIndex(SearchIndex, Indexable):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    likes = IntegerField()

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def get_model(self):
        return User

    def prepare_likes(self, obj):
        # Logging here just because it's the first "prepare" function.
        log.debug("Indexing %s: %d" % (obj.__class__.__name__, obj.pk))
        return obj.get_all_likes()
```

I have one object in my database. When I run `update_index`, the `log.debug` is printed 3 times for the object with `pk` `1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it is the base class calling the `prepare` method after the initial `prepare_likes`? Another idea could be that there are multiple indexes in the haystack settings?

Comment: @user1464664 thanks! The first hypothesis is a bit odd unless I misunderstand? It's weird that the object would be prepared multiple times regardless of what the base class does... it's taking now 3 times as much as needed. The second hypothesis... yes `UserIndex` is not my only index, but other indexes are for other models. Is this what you meant?

Comment: For multiple indexes suggestion, I am referring to what might be in the settings.py. Haystack will loop for each index found in the `HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS` setting. I have seen this with multi-language projects.

Comment: @user1464664 ah ok. No, I only have one connection to one Elasticsearch server. Any more ideas? It's the only `SearchIndex` that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: @user1464664 never mind, please ignore: `prepare_likes`, where the logging happens, was called by another prepare function. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

The issue was simply that the `prepare_likes` method was additionally called by other `prepare_` methods, causing multiple log statements and making me think that the whole indexing was happening more than once.